# c-lightning is working on Rust language bindings. How does this compare to the language bindings work LDK has been doing?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, lightning-development-kit

I know [LDK](https://github.com/lightningdevkit/ldk-c-bindings) (rust-lightning) has been doing a lot of language bindings work to support various languages (C, Go, Java, Swift etc).

c-lightning is now [working](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/pull/5010) on language bindings itself so you can build say c-lightning plugins in Rust.

How does this language bindings work compare to the approach LDK has been taking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was answered during a c-lightning developer call on January 10th 2022. The [transcript](https://github.com/bitcointranscripts/bitcointranscripts/blob/master/c-lightning/2022-01-10-developer-call.md) is anonymized by default.

> There we are talking about different bindings. These are the bindings that we use for our RPC interface. I think when rust-lightning is talking about bindings they are talking much more about having a C API that they can compile into their own apps. Whereas this is inter daemon communication or daemon with plugin or daemon with front end. The C API that rust-lightning is building is most likely to be consumed by a binary directly. For example if you are building a Java application or an Android application you will most likely be using GNI to talk to rust-lightning instead of some other Java code. I think they are referring to that. Whereas this is mostly inter daemon and inter process communication. We have a connection or a file descriptor where we write stuff out.